# Js date format from google calendar event

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, google-calendar-api

I got event from google calendar and event has end time if format **2018-07-19T00:00:00+03:00** . How can I get normal date from this? Year, month, day, hour, minutes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment` or `date-fns`
they are librairies to format dates.

Example:

```
import moment from 'moment';
const day = moment('2018-07-19T00:00:00+03:00').format('DD');
```

if you are not using ES6/ES7, you can add the cdn to your project and use it the same way.

If you don't like using librairies, you can do it using js `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use the `Date` object of JavaScript :

`let date = new Date('2018-07-19T00:00:00+03:00');`

Here's the link to documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

This object as many method to get part of the date or to get representation of it.
As the documentation show in the example you can event do basic math beetween Dates